# How to run a hardhat node in the cloud

Tags: hardhat, mocha

I have a set of tests i run locally using hardhat and mocha. However, I would like to run these tests on every push to prod. How can I start a hardhat node in the cloud for the testing.

Comment: To run the Hardhat and Mocha tests on every push to production, one approach would be to use GitHub Actions. 

GitHub Actions can be configured to automatically run tests whenever code is pushed to main.

The action workflow would start by setting up Node.js and installing dependencies. 

It would then run the build and test scripts. Any failures would cause the action to fail, preventing deployment until tests pass. 

This provides continuous testing in the cloud without needing local infrastructure.